# Rails: Custom form (get), drops param when submitted

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a Rails search form and I am configuring the results page via a param (show=list or show=grid - giving the user control on whether they want to see results in a simple list or a more verbose grid / card layout).

I have this code to construct the form and I am expecting the resulting URL to be something like /search?query=searchstring&show=list, however the "show=list" part isn't passed through so the result URL is /search?query=searchstring

What am I doing wrong?
(Note - there is a stimulus controller attached as well but that is for a different functionality - to dynamically create a little drop down with search results; but the idea is that if the user clicks the "search" button, they are redirected to a full search results page).

Form Code:

```
<%= form_with url: search_index_path(show: 'list'), method: 'GET',
  class: 'search__form peer',
  data: {
    controller: 'quick-search',
    action: 'invalid->quick-search#hideValidationMessage:capture input->quick-search#search'
  } do |f| %>
  <input id="query" name="query" type="search"
    pattern=".*\w+.*" required
    placeholder="Search..." data-quick-search-target="searchinput" />
  <button type="submit" class="searchbutton">
    <svg
      xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
      class="smallicon"
      fill="none"
      viewBox="0 0 24 24"
      stroke="currentColor"
      stroke-width="2"
    >
      <path
        stroke-linecap="round"
        stroke-linejoin="round"
        d="M21 21l-6-6m2-5a7 7 0 11-14 0 7 7 0 0114 0z"
      />
    </svg>
  </button>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Just a shot in the dark, but I wonder if `show` is a reserved word.  Can you try changing your param name to something like `show_type` and see what happens?

Comment: Why don't you try a hidden input ? There may be some override here

Comment: I had no issues using "show" in other places but it is actually a good comment @Bek :) ... I will change that. This is definitively not the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a hidden field

add this at end of the bottom of the form_with

```
<%= hidden_field_tag :show, "list" %>
```